# Экспорт внешнего application.properties в Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot

Например, я хочу разделить application.properties на один корневой и несколько дочерних.

> Здесь не имеется ввиду, что у меня есть несколько модулей и в каждом
>   свой application.properties.

Имеется ввиду, что application.properties может быть очень большим и трудным для поддержки.

Есть ли решение ?

Answer (score 1):

Если используется spring (boot), то можно разделить на любое количество файлов и, например, в любом из конфигурационных бинов в аннотации PropertySource передавать названия всех файлов, например:

```
@PropertySource(value = {
    "classpath:one.properties",
    "classpath:two.properties",
    "classpath:another.properties",
    "classpath:some.properties"
})
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {}
```

Либо конфигурировать бины с помощью PropertyResourceBundle.getBundle("configName")